# SWT Right click menu item selection listener not getting called.

Tags: java, events, windows-7, swt, eclipse-rcp

We have a client who complains that the right click functionality suddenly stopped working. So I debugged a little and found that the RCP app is not throwing any exceptions, just that the right click menuItem listeners are not getting called. Here is the outline of the code that we use in our app.

```
rightClickListener = new Listener(){
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            TRACER.trace("Handle event for tree's right click listener");

            if(treeComp.tree.getSelectionCount()>0 && PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().getBoolean("RightClickEnabled")){
                TRACER.trace(currSelection + " selected.");
                        rcmenu.selectionMenu(event);

            }
        }


    };
    treeComp.tree.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect,rightClickListener);
```

And the actual menu and menu items are created in the rcmenu class. Listeners are added there.

```
public void selectionMenu(Event event){

    TRACER.trace("Begin selectionMenu()");


    shell = tree.getShell();
    display = tree.getDisplay();        
     Menu menu = null;
     try{
         menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.POP_UP);
     }catch(Exception e){
         ERROR_REPORTER.report("Error when creating menu ", e);
     }
    menu.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener(){

        @Override
        public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
            TRACER.trace("Menu Disposed");

        }

    });
    TreeItem[] selectionItems = tree.getSelection();



        if(selectionItems.length=1){
            addMenuItems(menu);
        }

        handleSetEnableLogic(); //after adding the menu items in addMenuItems(menu) we enable them here in this method. 


    menu.setLocation(event.x, event.y);
    menu.setVisible(true);

    try{
        while (!menu.isDisposed() && menu.isVisible()) {

            boolean readAndDispatch = display.readAndDispatch();
            if (!readAndDispatch){
                display.sleep();
            }           
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        ERROR_REPORTER.report("Error during dispatch event ",e);
    }
    try{
        menu.dispose();
    }catch(Exception e){
        ERROR_REPORTER.report("Error during menu dispose ",e);
    }
    TRACER.trace("End selectionMenu()");
}
```

And the addMenuItems() method is as shown

```
item_modify = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH);
    item_modify.setText("Modify"); //Modify

    //"Modify"
    item_modify.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            BusyIndicator.showWhile(Display.getCurrent(), new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    TRACER.trace("Handle event for right click menu-- modify: ");
                    //listener code                         
                }
            });
        }
    });
    item_modify.setEnabled(false);
```

The right click menu is getting created, the item_modify menu item is enabled. Nothing is disposed. When we select on the item_modify menu item the display.readAndDispatch is returning true hence the display is not going to sleep. But at that point the selection listener for item_modify is not getting fired. Then the menu becomes invisible and comes out of the while loop and gets disposed as expected. But  the point is I am not understanding why the selection listener is not getting fired. Is there is a way to know if an event is fired? Does any group policies on the machine affect how the events are fired?

Every other listener in the application works fine.

Comment: Why do you add another event loop to your application (the `readAndDispatch` part)? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I removed the event loop and it is working fine. Does the eclipse framework provide the event loop for menus too since this is an RCP app? I have been adding event loops to menus all these days.But this is not solving why the selection listener is not getting called when the menu item is selected :(

Comment: AFAIK, all SWT / Eclipse RCP application only have *one* event loop. A menu doesn't need its own one.

Comment: How can the selection be fired when the `MenuItem` is disabled (`item_modify.setEnabled(false)`)?

Comment: I am enabling it in the  handleSetEnableLogic() method just after adding it in the addMenuItems() method.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. If you can come up with minimal testable code example (SWT application) that I can just copy/paste, I'd be able to debug and find out.